# Validating <md-autocomplete> in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, md-autocomplete

I have an `<md-autocomplete>` which has a control that's required. The control is touched and invalid, however it doesn't display any error.

```
<md-form-field>
    <input mdInput id="comboInput" placeholder="{{ label }}" aria-label="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" (blur)="blur($event)" (change)="handleChange($event)">
    <md-icon mdSuffix class="fa fa-times" (click)="handleInputClear()"></md-icon>
    <md-error *ngIf="control.invalid && control.touched">{{"itemIsRequired" | translate: "" : [label] }}</md-error>
    <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)="handleOptionSelect($event)">
        <md-option *ngFor="let item of data" [value]="item">
            {{ item[textField] }}
        </md-option>
    </md-autocomplete>
</md-form-field>
```

I haven't found any documentation on validating this component, so I'm kinda lost.

For error handling I added this code and I can see both `control.touched` & `control.invalid` are true

```
<md-error *ngIf="control.invalid && control.touched">{{"itemIsRequired" | translate: "" : [label] }}</md-error>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `control`? You input doesn't look like it is connected to an NgControl like NgModel or a FormControl.

Comment: @WillHowell control is the formcontrol which I use to validate this component. I pass it from my main component.

Comment: Ah with a custom value accessor? So the md-error will already automatically show when the mdInput's control is invalid and touched, but it only works out of the box when the mdInput has an attached NgControl. Take a look at [Custom Error Matchers](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#custom-error-matcher) to allow you to show the error whenever you want.

Comment: @WillHowell the problem is that the error doesn't show even though the formcontrol of the element says it's invalid & tocuhed

Comment: The md-errors only show when the form control hooked up to the `<input mdInput />` is invalid and touched. It doesn't look like that input has any form control attached to it in your code snippet, so they will never show automatically.